# I Want to know the name of the fonts is used in vs code user setting

Tags: vscode-extensions, visual-studio-code, vscode-tasks

I want to know the name of the font which is used in vscode user settings

[image]

Comment: The font is specified in the global `settings.json` file. Press Ctrl+, on Windows. (Modify the Ctrl to a Cmd on MAC)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Visual Studio Code is basically a web browser. Hence you can open the developer view (Help -> Toggle Developer Tools) in it to get directly to the HMTL DOM:

[image]